# FIlter Rows in a Dataframe based on Variable's Total Occurrences

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I'm trying to remove observations with variables that I don't have enough observations of.

For instance in this dataframe there's

5 observations for A & B,

3 for C,

2 for D,

and 1 for E.

```
df.1 <- c('A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'E')
df.2 <- c('B', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A')

df <- data.frame(df.1, df.2)
df

# df.1 df.2
# 1    A    B
# 2    B    D
# 3    B    D
# 4    C    A
# 5    C    A
# 6    C    B
# 7    B    A
# 8    E    A
```

If I need a min of three observations I'd like to remove any with D and E to get something such as:

```
 final.df.1 final.df.2
1          A          B
2          C          A
3          C          A
4          C          B
5          B          A
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, get the frequency count with `table` and use that to `subset` the columns having only those names that have frequency greater than 'n'

```
n <- 3
nm1 <- names(which(table(unlist(df)) >= n))
subset(df, Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, `%in%`, nm1)))
  df.1 df.2
1    A    B
4    C    A
5    C    A
6    C    B
7    B    A
```